# How do I raise a SOAP Fault with a structured detail element in Spyne?

Tags: python, soapfault, spyne

The [Spyne manual](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/03_types.html#fault) points out that the right way to create SOAP Faults with Spyne is to raise instances of `spyne.model.fault.Fault` (or your own subclass):

```
@add_metaclass(ComplexModelMeta)
class Fault(ComplexModelBase, Exception):
    # ...
```

I'm trying to understand why it subclasses `ComplexModelBase`. My initial assumption was that I declare the elements I want to go into the SOAP Fault's `<detail>` element in my `Fault` subclass, like so:

```
class MyApplicationError(Fault):
    __namespace__ = 'http://myapplication.com/ns'
    _type_info = [
        ('reason', Unicode),
    ]
```

However, when actually raising this exception, it looks like I have to pass a plain dict into the `detail` parameter of the constructor.

What is the best practice for filling the `detail` with a structured set of data? Do I even declare this structure in my `Fault` subclass?
If yes, how do I fill it? If not, why does `Fault` subclass `ComplexModelBase`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Fault(detail={'foo': {'bar': 123}})
```

will serialize to:

```
<ns0:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <faultcode>soap11env:Server</faultcode>
  <faultstring>Fault</faultstring>
  <faultactor></faultactor>
  <detail>
    <foo>
      <bar>123</bar>
    </foo>
  </detail>
</ns0:Fault>
```

You can write a new constructor for `Fault` in a subclass to make it easier to generate the details dict. E.g.:

```
class SuperFault(Fault):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        super(SuperFault, self).__init__('Server.SuperFault', 'E001234',
                                detail={'SuperFault': {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}})
```

Please note that due to some stupid limitation, the length of the dict passed to detail must be 1. Please file an issue if that's a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's basically as far as I got. But can I not generate my detail element from the `__type_info__` of a `ComplexModel`, similarly to how I generate a SOAP response from my own `ComplexModel` subclasses?

Comment: There's two major issues with this solution:  
a) Using the dictionary method you outlined, I don't need to declare the Fault subclass anymore (or declare it as `_throws` on the `@rpc` decorator). Then, I'm missing the Fault in the `<soap:fault>` on the binding and the `<wsdl:fault>` on the portType.  
b) On the other hand, if I do declare it, and use this as the exception to raise with the `detail` argument on the constructor, Spyne will write the fields in the Fault twice, once in the `<detail>` element, and once outside next to it.

Comment: Additionally, Spyne always prefixes the content of the `<faultcode>` element with `senv:`, even thought that namespace is not declared. I generally don't see anything in the [spec on SOAP Fault Codes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383510) that would imply that they ever need to be namespace-prefixed.